# make for compiling -- all *.c files

Tags: linux, makefile

To compile two files i have created a makefile where i use to mention the object name.

```
OBJ = led-player_backup.o led-player.o
```

Now if my folder contains 100 files do i have to write name of 100 object in makefile. Is it possible to write some pattern rule in this case to make object file for all *.c files.

here is my original makefile. What to modify in it to achieve the same ?

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Makefile for building tapp
#
# Copyright 2010 FriendlyARM (http://www.arm9.net/)
#

ifndef DESTDIR
DESTDIR            ?= /opt/FriendlyARM/tiny6410/linux/rootfs_qtopia_qt4
endif

CFLAGS              = -Wall -O2  # wall is for warning show and 02 is optiminisation level 2
CC                    = arm-linux-gcc   # compiler name
INSTALL             = install         # 

TARGET              = led-player

OBJ = led-player_backup.o led-player.o

#all: $(TARGET) 

all: $(OBJ)


%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#$< -o $@


install: $(TARGET)
    $(INSTALL) $^ $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin

clean :
    rm -rf *.o $(TARGET)


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: $(PHONY) install clean

# End of file
# vim: syntax=make
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
```

Comment: One more link .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971865/patsubst-on-makefile